# how to create objects with rigid body center and insubstantial exterior

Tags: animation, physics, soft-body, rigidbody

I want to model atoms/molecules banging into each other and allowing the outer shells of electrons to interpenetrate a bit.  I have tried using soft body physics and the deformations aren't exactly what I am looking for.  I want things that look like they don't bend when interpenetrating for some X % of distance, and then the cores totally repell each other without deformations.

To that end, I think that I want to create objects that have a rigid body interior with a visible but physically insubstantial shell that is a duplicate of the rigid body scaled up by about 1.1.  The idea is that the objects will bounce around in an animation and the shells will interpenetrate, but when the rigid cores collide they will bounce off of each other.

I would be happy to use single objects that allow X % penetration during a rigid body collision,  but I don't know if that is possible.

I know how to do the rigid body collisions, and I know how to join a shell object and a core object together to make a dingus that moves as if it were a single object.  I don't know how to set the properties of the inner to rigid body and the outer to whatever I need to use.   Remember, the outer must be visible in the animation.  The inner core will always be hidden.  Or if there is a better solution I will be grateful to learn of it.

Thanks

Comment: you should add a link to a video/animation how it should look like.